# Как добавить заголовки в таблице выводимого отчёта

Tags: c#, winforms

Дана таблица:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что добавить в код, чтобы выводились такие же заголовки? Иначе в Word выходит это:
[image]

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Document doc = app.Documents.Add(Visible: true);
    Range r = doc.Range();

    Table t = doc.Tables.Add(r, 1, 6);
    t.Borders.Enable = 1;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-LRHFEMI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Delomedika;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Zayavki", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int j = 1;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        t.Rows.Add();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            t.Cell(j, i).Range.Text = reader.GetValue(i - 1).ToString();
                        }
                        j = j + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            t.Rows.Last.Delete();
            doc.Save();
            try
            {
                doc.Close();
                app.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception help)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(help.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception help)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(help.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: просто перед заполнением создайте новую строку в таблице вордовской и в цикле заполните её текстом заголовков из `DataFridView`

Comment: я не особо понимаю как это кодом сделать, поэтому и задал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто перед заполнением создайте новую строку в вордовской таблице и в цикле заполните её текстом заголовков из `DataGridView`:

```
t.Rows.Add();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns; i++)
    t.Cell(1, i + 1).Range.Text = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
```